# Getting empty parameter from url

Tags: go

I'm trying to get parameter for the url I send in Postman to the server.
This is the GET request:

```
localhost:8081/getTopProducts?store_id=storeidteststring
```

This is what I have in the server:

```
func GetTopProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    storeID := mux.Vars(r)["store_id"]
    id := r.Header.Get("store_id")

    fmt.Println(storeID) <-- printing empty string
    fmt.Println(id) <-- printing empty string

    w.Header().Set("Server", storeID)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

This is the handler:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/getTopProducts", db.GetTopProducts).Methods("GET")
```

I can't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you add your handler funcs ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus added.

Comment: It's `r.URL.Query().Get("store_id")`. `mux.Vars` is for path parameters, not query parameters. `r.Header.Get` is for HTTP headers not query parameters.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried this, also getting nothing.

Comment: @JohnDoah as an alternative to `r.URL.Query().Get("store_id")` you can also use `r.FormValue("store_id")`, however if `r.URL.Query` doesn't work for you then something else is wrong, you may have a typo somewhere or something because `r.URL.Query().Get` how one reads query parameters.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! I tried again and it works, but I really don't understand way it didn't. I check for typo few times but couldn't see anything.

Comment: @mkopriva, you can use `mux.Vars` for query params, but you have to define those query params for the path: `router.Queries("store_id","{storeId}")`